# How can I open a new Stage on the external monitor?

Tags: java, javafx, external-display

I have an external monitor plugged into my laptop. I want to display a new `Stage` on this external screen in fullscreen, undecorated and modal mode. I know how to achieve all of this in pure Java/Swing combination, but I'm stucked with JavaFX implementation of such functionality.

I know, there is a `Screen` API, which I can use e.g to get screen list, say:

`List<Screen> allScreens = Screen.getScreens();`

...but I don't know where I could go from here.

**UPDATE : 2014/08/03, 22:21**

I've found the way to solve my problem, so I've decided to share my approach to it. So far I haven't found a better solution.

```
Button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {
        List<Screen> allScreens = Screen.getScreens();
        if (allScreens.size() > 1) {
            Screen secondaryScreen = allScreens.get(1);
            Rectangle2D bounds = secondaryScreen.getVisualBounds();

            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
            stage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
            stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
            stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());

            stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.show();

        } else {
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setFullScreen(true);

            stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You are using it perfectly !